# How to add and remove class elements based on window width?

Tags: javascript, php

As the titles implies, I am trying to resize my page based on the width of the screen it is displaying on. Currently this is what my code will display:

```
echo "<div class=\"col-6\"><div class=\"videoTitle\">Dyno 1a</div><iframe src='cam1a.shtml' width='100%' height='240' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe></div>";

echo "<div class=\"col-6\"><div class=\"videoTitle\">Dyno 1b</div><iframe src='cam1b.shtml' width='100%' height='240' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe></div>";

echo "<div class=\"col-4\"><div class=\"videoTitle\">Dyno 2</div><iframe src='cam2.shtml' width='100%' height='240' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe></div>";

echo "<div class=\"col-4\"><div class=\"videoTitle\">Dyno 3</div><iframe src='cam3.shtml' width='100%' height='240' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe></div>";

echo "<div class=\"col-4\"><div class=\"videoTitle\">Dyno 4</div><iframe src='cam4.shtml' width='100%' height='240' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe></div>";
```

And this is how I am trying to resize my data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    $( ".col-4" ).addClass(".col-12");
    $( ".col-4" ).removeClass(".col-4");

    $( ".col-6" ).addClass(".col-12");
    $( ".col-6" ).removeClass(".col-6");
  } else if ($(window).width() <= 992) {
    $( ".col-4" ).addClass(".col-6");
    $( ".col-4" ).removeClass(".col-4");
  }
});
```

Currently when I resize my data it will display the original format, which cuts off the image that is displaying. How could I rearrange my code so that my data will adjust to the window width?

Comment: Do not do that. It is 2023, use media queries. Also PHP does not know anything about the device, because it runs on server side. It looks like you are using something bootstrap similar, so check out for example for classes like `xs-col-4` or `xl-col-6`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thanks, this has actually helped out a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution to your problem is more of a CSS responsive design solution than JavaScript and PHP.

First, set your [document viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp):

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Also:

1. Do NOT use large fixed width elements
2. Since screen dimensions and width in CSS pixels vary widely between devices, content should not rely on a particular viewport width to render well.
3. Use CSS media queries to apply different styling for small and large screens - Setting large absolute CSS widths for page elements will cause the element to be too wide for the viewport on a smaller device. Instead, consider using relative width values, such as width: 100%. Also, be careful of using large absolute positioning values. It may cause the element to fall outside the viewport on small devices.